# How to prevent error when closing a turtle screen?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I have this simple code :

```
import turtle

s = turtle.Screen()
s.bgcolor('black')

obj = turtle.Turtle()

while True:
    s.update()
```

And when I close the window, this error comes up :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Visual Studio Code Projects\SortingAlgorithm1\main.py", line 10, in <module>
    s.update()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\turtle.py", line 1304, in update       
    t._update_data()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\turtle.py", line 2647, in _update_data 
    self.screen._incrementudc()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\turtle.py", line 1293, in _incrementudc
    raise Terminator
turtle.Terminator
```

Is there a way to prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

Replace your final:

```
while True:
    s.update()
```

with

```
s.mainloop()
```

This `while` loop seems to be a common introduction to turtle paradigm that is really the wrong thing to do.  A complete example:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

screen = Screen()
screen.bgcolor('black')

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.color('white')

screen.mainloop()
```